# Hola, ¿cuál es la forma correcta de retornar y capturar un array bidimensional de un método?

Tags: java, array, poo, array-bidimensional

Estoy implementando el siguiente código en busca que después de leer una archivo txt que tiene una matriz, sea almacenada en un array bidimensional de tipo entero. Y posteriormente deseo capturar ese array desde el método principal. Sin embargo cuando retorno la matriz me dice que la variable no está declara en el método. El código es el siguiente

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
   int[][]mat = leerArchivo();
}
```

public static int[][] leerArchivo() {

```
    try {
        FileReader r = new FileReader("Matriz.txt");
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(r);

        String temp = "";
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((temp = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(temp);
        }
        String[] numbers = lines.get(0).split(",");
        int x = lines.size(); // Cantidad de lineas (Filas)
        int y = numbers.length; //Cantidad de números por linea (Columnas)            
        int[][] matrix = new int[x][y];

        //Llenamos la matriz linea por linea 
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            String[] line = lines.get(i).split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
            
        }
      //  Tripleta t = new Tripleta(matrix);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha encontrado el archivo");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning");
    }
       return matrix; //Aquí me dice que no encuentra la variable
}
```

Comment: Hola Edward. Esto ocurre porque estás declarando la matriz dentro del bloque `try`, por tanto, `matrix` no existe fuera de ese bloque. Antes del `try` escribe algo cómo `int[][] matrix = null` y luego ya dentro usas `matrix = new int[x][y];`.

Comment: Perfecto. Ya me funcionó. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez No se yo si esta pregunta tiene un error tipográfico (como alguien ha votado para cerrarla) o si merece la pena que pongas tu comentario como respuesta.  Yo de java ni idea, pero a mi no me parece un error tipográfico, sino que tu comentario efectivamente responde a su pregunta.

Comment: @EdwardAndrésTabares Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta de JaimeMenéndez si te ha servido para solucionar tu problema y para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema radica en que estás declarando `matrix` dentro del bloque `try`, por tanto, `matrix` no existe fuera de ese bloque. En `java`, el alcance de una variable se define dentro del conjunto de llaves `{}` en que se declara, y fuera de esas llaves la variable no existe.

Para solucionarlo, declara la variable `matrix` antes del `try`:

```java
int[][] matrix = null;
try {
  // ... Resto del código..
}
```

E inicializa `matrix` dentro del `try` usando:

```java
matrix = new int[x][y];
```

Nota que he eliminado la declaración `int[][]`, ya que la variable ya fue declarada antes. Con esos simples cambios tu problema quedará resuelto.